# Can we say " the most similar passages"?

Tags: superlative-degree

A comparison of the most similar passages from this tradition could shed light, I hope, on the interpretation of the first Palladan monosyllabic substantive.

Comment: Clearly you *can say* (= *are able to say*) - but whether it makes sense is a separate issue! ;)  But the more important points are "comparison with what?", and "similar to what?"  I don't understand what your sentence is trying to say.  What are the passages similar to? .. to one another? or to something in another sentence which you haven't included?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you can see from this [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most%20similar&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmost%20similar%3B%2Cc0), the expression "most similar" has been rising in use since about 1750 in the written English language. So to speak of "most similar passages" is correct English usage, if that was your question.